# SQL Rounding my INT results when dividing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am asking a followup question to a post earlier. ([SQL: Overflow error for type INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880445/sql-overflow-error-for-type-int/41880518?noredirect=1#comment70946311_41880518)). The issue I am having now is converting the results for @SUMX2Y and @SUMX2X2 to be FLOAT. I have tried multiple different methods and still having issues. Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong here? I did not include my conversion attempts, but they included CAST and CONVERT as far as the individual level of the equation.

```
CREATE TABLE #Set1
(
    X BIGINT,
    Y BIGINT
)
INSERT INTO #Set1 
VALUES (220, 630)
      ,(350, 940)
      ,(450, 1140)


DECLARE @SUMX BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMY BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMX2 BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMY2 BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMX3 BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMX4 BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMXX BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMXY_ BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMXY BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMXX2 BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMX2Y BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMX2Y_ BIGINT
DECLARE @SUMX2X2 BIGINT
DECLARE @N INT

    SET @N = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Set1)
    SET @SUMY = (SELECT SUM(Y) FROM #Set1)
    SET @SUMX2 = (SELECT SUM(POWER(X,2)) FROM #Set1)
    SET @SUMX4 = (SELECT SUM(POWER(X,4)) FROM #Set1)

    SET @SUMX2Y_ = (SELECT SUM(POWER(X,2)*Y) FROM #Set1)

    SET @SUMX2Y = @SUMX2Y_ - (@SUMX2*@SUMY)/(@N)
    SET @SUMX2X2 = @SUMX4 - (POWER(@SUMX2,2)/@N)

    PRINT @SUMX2Y
    PRINT @SUMX2X2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just changing the BIGINT to FLOAT for now. I am unsure if down the road it causes issues. we'll see

Answer (score 0):

Use NUMERIC(18,2) or whatever precision you want to keep. Using float this will keep decimal precision values until you explicitly pass decimal values

Below code you can use

```
CREATE TABLE #Set1
(
    X NUMERIC(18,2),
    Y NUMERIC(18,2)
)
INSERT INTO #Set1 
VALUES (220, 630)
      ,(350, 940)
      ,(450, 1140)


DECLARE @SUMX NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMY NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMX2 NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMY2 NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMX3 NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMX4 NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMXX NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMXY_ NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMXY NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMXX2 NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMX2Y NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMX2Y_ NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @SUMX2X2 NUMERIC(18,2)
DECLARE @N NUMERIC(18,2)

    SET @N = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Set1)
    SET @SUMY = (SELECT SUM(Y) FROM #Set1)
    SET @SUMX2 = (SELECT SUM(POWER(X,2)) FROM #Set1)
    SET @SUMX4 = (SELECT SUM(POWER(X,4)) FROM #Set1)

    SET @SUMX2Y_ = (SELECT SUM(POWER(X,2)*Y) FROM #Set1)

    SET @SUMX2Y = @SUMX2Y_ - (@SUMX2*@SUMY)/(@N)
    SET @SUMX2X2 = @SUMX4 - (POWER(@SUMX2,2)/@N)

    PRINT @SUMX2Y
    PRINT @SUMX2X2
```

Use below script for Float & Numeric difference

```
DECLARE @SUMX NUMERIC(18,2) = 100 

DECLARE @SUMX1 FLOAT = 100 

SELECT @SUMX,@SUMX1
```